# Laravel Nova metrics inside resource record

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

How can i see metrics inside each resource record with data related to the current project like this capture?

[image]

Comment: Did you already define a [Custom Metric](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html)?

Comment: @Sven i have a metric running in the projects resource but i don't know if is posible to embed the metric inside a record. For example, inside the `Tuesday test` project, show the related tasks count, where tasks is a related model to project.